# Can't reference new CocoaTouch class in xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I created a new ViewController in my xcode storyboard and created a new corresponding cocoatouch class that is a subclass of UIViewController. When I tried to assign the new class to the storyboard viewcontroller it showed up in the custom class dropdown bar but when I selected it the name of the storyboard view controller remained the default "View Controller Scene". When I selected other previous cocoatouch classes from the dropdown menu the class did get assigned to the viewcontroller. I also tried creating a new instance of the class in another class for the purposes of creating a segue and the class was not recognized. Did I do something wrong in creating the class?

The following code gives the error "Use of undeclared identifier abcdController":

```
ABCDViewController *abcdController;
abcdController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

[Storyboard View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNY6w.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This post could probably benefit from including some source code in the question.

Comment: I added a code snippet and an image of my storyboard, hopefully that clears some things up

Comment: I sort of solved part of my own problem. The segue issue is just because I forgot to import the ABCDViewController to that file. It seems like the lack of naming of the view controller in the storyboard might just be a glitch that doesn't really matter.

Comment: Good to hear! By the way: you should be able to answer your own question below if you have fully solved the problem.